# Verifying/validating a JWT token created in PHP in .NET

Tags: c#, php

I have a JWT token created using PHP that I need to then use in a .NET app (framework version 4.5.1). The token is generated in PHP using the following code (relies on https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt library):

```
use Lcobucci\JWT\Builder;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac\Sha256;

$tokenBuilder = new Builder();
$tokenSigner  = new Sha256();

$token = (string)$tokenBuilder
    ->setIssuer('localhost:8081')
    ->setAudience('myaudience')
    ->setIssuedAt(time())
    ->setExpiration(time() + 86400)
    ->sign($tokenSigner, '710VWV0zby')
    ->getToken();

return $token;
```

I've been able to read the token fine in C#, but am struggling mightily to figure out how to validate and verify the token signature.

```
TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    ValidateIssuer = true
};

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

// THIS IS TO TEST IF TOKEN CAN BE READ
/*var jwtToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(token);

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(jwtToken.Issuer);*/

SecurityToken validatedToken = null;
try
{
    tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Invalid! :(");
}

if (validatedToken != null) {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Valid! :)");
}
```

Obviously, my code can't verify any signature, given that there's not even any mention of a SHA-256 key anywhere. I'm assuming I need to include that somehow in the TokenValidationParameters there's a property I need to set, and I'm guessing SigningToken would be the one, but I don't really know where to start to specify an HMAC SHA 256 key.

Answer (score 1):

You need somehow export certificate that was using for token creation. It can be file in .pem format for example. After that create crypto provider using data from that certificate

```
  public static RSACryptoServiceProvider CreateRsaCryptoProviderFromX509Certificate()
    {
        byte[] certData = Convert.FromBase64String(_CERTIFICATE);
        X509Certificate2 x509Cert = new X509Certificate2();
        x509Cert.Import(certData);
        var x509PublicKeyXml = x509Cert.PublicKey.Key.ToXmlString(false);

        RSACryptoServiceProvider RsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        RsaProvider.FromXmlString(x509PublicKeyXml);
        return RsaProvider;
    }
```

where _CERTIFICATE store data from .pem file without leading coments

```
 string _CERTIFICATE = @"   DD5NYXRyaXg0Ml9mNThlMzdkLWU2ZjktNGU0Yi05MzVlLTNhMDFi
                            NzU2N2I5YjAeFw0xNjEyMzExNTE1MjNaFw00MjAxMDcxNTE1MjNaMEkxRzBFBgNVBAMMPk1hdHJp
                            eDQyX0FDU19SZWx5aW5nUGFydHlfZmY1OGUzN2QtZTZmOS00ZTRiLTkzNWUtM2EwMWI3NTY3Yjli
                            MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAho5G6pY9QJs/945aQ1w8oiF/17ZNGsNY
                            ul5G/+TprN7KfgzT9u+A588f4Z4B8z5QJlwIUeH33iuRcV0AIHd9MnEKR56IdOLLlNWNPvRAG5FJ
                            Wt4XPlaG+bE/oyuqxqpQM1KJ0iN74K/WLXM8ZdQlq7gTgtLS+icZH3i2arC8rdobh3zRk1wbUVXn
                            kjR4CASy+07LZwbVVp2g3pOsuy5AWBURIynQ7z3zj+u7NMF42htLOEzISl3Qb3BMOoXFMm93UGwp
                            B/Ae+zpWFWeh6190ipcUMXoAOfdh9VZUZX9C7OI/3plOiwKUvwfBQyLR8C/4uiTcCTp1i8fS0bta
                            jkPhdQIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQA3fmwEgej+BhB7dkw+0TWEDiIC9cXR4uW7kElM
                            7+L7ARmUYVpAx05Z8oarsR0zm1u3ZYR00y3eLhw5RcXN6hC5jb5HYSQZERdqlzvS6bU6xJ57H7tC
                            KuPADkYmuPnRM/cdMKPeSG3ZHnHcTgJx62hFloPWbGPr9VLVp4R4coUgtuZMtlFvXamjpCNYSpob
                            N9wzk36r/4c+Nd/n+4DwqIaVzgEXHXkOUtOZhTYh7SG5WJVUSep5cIq3SBGzLn8oXCjiqn72zJ7C
                            vn5/ekaC1nzMDMcga5qWQNdLd/rXt65ZMbB/JhM+Ee9TIvmrrDXlvRh2cv7GtoTtPYEbIdVvrF+W";
```

for validation create token handler, validation parameters and validate token with cryptoprovider

```
     public static bool ValidateJwt(string jwt)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler securityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = CreateRsaCryptoProviderFromX509Certificate();

        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidAudience ="urn:6c23aaa7-6da8-4941-98b0-62f63cd146",
            ValidIssuer = "https://accounts.issuer.com",
            IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa)
        };
        SecurityToken token;
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = securityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwt, validationParameters, out token);

        return claimsPrincipal.IsInRole("Admin");
    }
```